# how i convert this to functional component in react native

Tags: react-native, react-functional-component

```
                let { eventDate } = this.state;
             
                if (eventDate <= 0) {
                    this.setState({ isTimerOver: true});  
                }
```

Here I need to write this in functional components. can you help me to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [useState](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usestate.asp) hook in functional component

```
import { useState } from 'react';
...

const yourFunctionName = () => {

const [ eventDate, setEventDate ] = useState(0) // set initial value here
// The first value eventDate , is our current state.
// The second value setEventDate, is the function that is used to update eventDate state

const [ isTimerOver, setIsTimerOver ] = useState(false) // set initial value

...
     if (eventDate <= 0) {
        setIsTimerOver(true); // function to update the state isTimerOver
     }
...

}

export default yourFunctionName;
```

Refer this : [React useState Hook](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usestate.asp)